# Using YOLO real-time detection, couldn't compile with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, real-time, detection

```
$ ./darknet imtest data/eagle.jpg
L2 Norm: 371.992218
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Original.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to Gray.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C1.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C2.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C3.png instead
Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to C4.png instead
$ ./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights football.mp4
Demo needs OpenCV for webcam images.
```

Although, I have write OpenCV=1 in the makefile, and I've opencv downloaded as well.

Here is my python and opencv version

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.2.0'
>>>
```

Very appreciate if anyone knows how to solve this problem

Comment: Probably the compilation didn't find OpenCV headers/libraries. Can you add the information you got during compilation?

Comment: Did you run the make file after changing to OpenCV=1?  The "import cv2" test only tells you that you have the OpenCV package installed for Python.  Did you install OpenCV?

Comment: could you run it on webcam video

Comment: @EladJoseph I'm using cmake-gui windows and it says Found OpenCV: {path to user}/conda/envs/tf_gpu/Library (found version "3.4.2"). Still the same error! :( I can't run the webcam nor any input video on alexeyab-darknet.

Answer (score -1):

Try remaking the project 
if remake is not installed then install it and do $remake darknet
then it should work .
worked fine for me

Comment: Is it equivalent to re-"cmake" for us Windows users?